# iterate over a hashmap in jquery

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, hashmap

In Spring MVC, I am using Google's Gson to convert a HashMap in json format in a controller that I send to a jsp page where i need to iterate over it using jquery.

The format of HashMap is:
The key is a POJO(Staff) &
The Value is another HashMap( the key of this HashMap is a POJO(Training) and the value is a normal Integer.)

The Staff class is like:

```
private String name;
private int number;
private Staff manager
```

The Training Class:

```
private int trainingID;
private String Subject
```

value for the inner HashMap

```
int numberOfTrainingDays.
```

The final HashMap parsed into Json which needs to iterated is:

```
Hashmap<Staff, HashMap<Training, numberOfTrainingDays>>
```

I tried this:

```
data = $.parseJSON(response);
$.each(data,function(index,value)
                {
                    alert("staff = " + index.name); // this alerts "undefined"
                    if(value != null){
                        $.each( value,function(training,trainingDays)
                        {
                            alert("training: "+training+"days = " + trainingDays);

                        });
                    }
                });
```

I even tried `staff.getName()` for which it says no function.

Actually the classes are quite different but i have simplified them for this question.
Kindly help.

Comment: Post the JSON String. It will be easier to investigate.

Comment: I don't think that if you have a map in Java that anything else than having the keys as String will make any sense in JSON notation since keys in JSON are always Strings.